# Postgres Group and order by range (specific values)

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table like this:

```
id           simcard          simcard_order
80769   56407503370245588410    1
80788   66329183922439284822    2
80803   20993658565113174305    0
80804   81781641934100313243    4
80852   71560493627263868232    3
80784   23739383536995189713    1
80793   42702512646659519628    2
80805   17990699721985463506    0
80832   08525531276567944345    4
80854   74478849586042090832    3
80786   22535328208807554315    1
80812   34317440773382930807    0
80826   36103390459816949722    2
80858   15439885499080289130    3
80862   26786481240939036248    4
80792   59566921916027957512    1
80813   98968026512101636608    0
80835   65834894114116066528    2
80864   17764015687751814947    4
80882   41427844162545991837    3
80887   41587969946566907740    4
80891   46059625228552654737    3
80824   76381392106884963712    1
80863   77385361462191701926    2
80868   46607630719285200008    0
80892   08860583551940471945    4
80899   85443153649210377733    3
80934   90908807112484733323    2
80937   25660906025678471304    0
80967   34298088103509862330    3
```

The column simcard_order has repeat values from 0 to 4.

I want to order the table like this:

```
id  simcard simcard_order
80769   56407503370245588410    0
80788   66329183922439284822    1
80803   20993658565113174305    2
80804   81781641934100313243    3
80852   71560493627263868232    4
80784   23739383536995189713    0
80793   42702512646659519628    1
80805   17990699721985463506    2
80832   08525531276567944345    3
80854   74478849586042090832    4
80786   22535328208807554315    0
80812   34317440773382930807    1
80826   36103390459816949722    2
80858   15439885499080289130    3
80862   26786481240939036248    4
....
```

and so on... So in this case I have 3 groups of (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
Always the order must be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

I have used this sql, but it does not work properly:

```
SELECT id, simcard, simcard_order
FROM tmp_pending_simcards
WHERE tmp_pending_simcards.simcard_order IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
ORDER BY (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT id, simcard, simcard_order
FROM tmp_pending_simcards tps
WHERE tps.simcard_order IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tps.simcard_order),
         tps.simcard_order;
```

Usually, you would have an `ORDER BY` as part of `ROW_NUMBER()`, but Postgres does not require it.

Comment: Very nice solution.